# Trigger form submit via jQuery alert confirmation

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, preventdefault

I'll make this as clear as I can.

Basically, my form allows you to delete players from a selection box.

When the user presses 'Delete', a confirmation box appears, telling the user that if they proceed, they can't get that data back. The intended behaviour is that when the user presses "OK", the deletion script will run and delete the player. If you remove the confirmation box and allow the default behaviour of the submit button, it works like I want it to. I would just be more professional if I could add that intermediate step.

Here is my relevant HTML Code:

```
 <form id="player-list" action="edit-player.php?playerid=22" method="post">

                <div id="player-box" class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 medium-offset-4 medium-4 columns">
                        <label>Team
                            <select id="all-players" name="team-division">
                            <?php
                                $SQL = "SELECT
                                            ID,
                                            firstName,
                                            lastName
                                        FROM
                                            players";
                                $playerResult = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);
                                $counter = 1;

                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($playerResult)) {
                                    echo '<option value="player-' . $row['ID'] . '">' . substr($row['firstName'], 0, 1) . " " . $row['lastName'] . '</option>';
                                }

                            ?>



                            </select>
                            <br />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 medium-2 medium-offset-4 columns ">
                        <a id="player-selection" class="button expanded radius success">Submit</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns end">
                        <input type="submit" id="player-deletion" class="button expanded radius alert" name="delete-player" value="Delete" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The input #player-deletion tag is what is important here.

Relevant jQuery code:

```
$("#player-deletion").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var x;
        if (confirm("This record will be permanentely deleted. Is that OK?") == true) {
            $(e).trigger('submit');
        } 
    });
```

This code doesn't work. I know I have to prevent the default action happening, but after the user has clicked 'OK', I would like to refire the submit function from the confirmation button.

Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: *"I would like to refire the submit function from the confirmation button."* why? it would have fired if you didn't prevent the default action anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just return whatever the `confirm` returns. `return false` would be the same as calling `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`. Stopping the event propagation is what will cancel the submit.

```
$("#player-deletion").click(function(e) {
    return confirm("This record will be permanentely deleted. Is that OK?");
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qyaazbsf/)

Comment: Sorry it took a while to get back to you. Been busy with work and other things. Your solution works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return false if user presses cancel in confirmation dialog. Otherwise it will go through default flow.

```
$("#player-deletion").on('click', function(e) {
    if (!confirm("This record will be permanentely deleted. Is that OK?")) {
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the if statement to

```
if (confirm("This record will be permanentely deleted. Is that OK?") == true) {
    //submit regardless
} else {
    e.preventDefault();//do something other here 
}
```